# How to detect iframe source from websocket in chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

How can you detect which iframe (if any) is the source of websocket creation using chrome dev tools protocol?

There doesn't appear to be anything in the [`Initator` response in chrome dev tools](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-webSocketCreated)

Chrome version: `Version 106.0.5249.119 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

[image]